# Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'contains')

Tags: reactjs, next.js

```
     const toggleCart = ()=> {
> 14 |     if (ref.current.clasList.contains('translate-x-full')){
     |                             ^
  15 |       ref.current.clasList.remove('translate-x-full')
  16 |       ref.current.clasList.add('translate-x-0')
  17 |     }
```

Facing Problem Everything Is Imported Correctly but Not Working

Comment: `clasList` vs `classList`

Answer (score 1):

You should fix the typo like Jakub mentioned.

To be safe it is good to use Optional Channing in Typescript - see details here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html